# Android faild build the project (Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.antlr.v4.runtime.CharStreams)

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'.

> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptExecution
> java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException (no error message)

- Try:
  Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Exception is:
  org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'.
  .......
  Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/antlr/v4/runtime/CharStreams
  ....

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.antlr.v4.runtime.CharStreams
... 45 more

Build.gradle file (module):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "org.bloodwyn.userdata"
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    configurations.all() {
        resolutionStrategy.force "org.antlr:antlr4-runtime:4.5.3"
        resolutionStrategy.force "org.antlr:antlr4-tool:4.5.3"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }

    compileOptions {
        coreLibraryDesugaringEnabled = true
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8.toString()
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    coreLibraryDesugaring "com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs:1.0.9"

    //kotlin
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"

    //android
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0"
    // For control over item selection of both touch and mouse driven selection
    implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview-selection:1.1.0-rc01"

    //retrofit
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0'

    //okhttp
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.7.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.7.2'

    //rxjava
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava3:rxjava:3.0.2'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava3:rxandroid:3.0.0'
    implementation "com.github.akarnokd:rxjava3-retrofit-adapter:3.0.0"

    //room
    def room_version = "2.2.5"

    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-rxjava2:$room_version"
    kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"

    //tests
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:truth:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.google.truth:truth:1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:core:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:rules:1.2.0'
    debugImplementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment-testing:1.2.5'

    //mock http server for tests
    testImplementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:mockwebserver:4.6.0'

    //room test
    testImplementation "androidx.room:room-testing:$room_version"
    
}
```

build.gradle project:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.72'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I added this:

```
configurations.all() {
        resolutionStrategy.force "org.antlr:antlr4-runtime:4.5.3"
        resolutionStrategy.force "org.antlr:antlr4-tool:4.5.3"
}
```

becouse if i dont i got the "ANTLR Tool version 4.5.3 used for code generation does not match the current runtime version 4.7.1ANTLR Runtime version 4.5.3 used for parser compilation does not match the current runtime version 4.7.1" exception

Answer (score 0):

I have some suggestions that may help some folks with auto-regenerating the ANTLR4 code for use on Android with Android Studio and Gradle. A complete working example of my setup is found [with my project here](https://github.com/maxieds/ChameleonMiniLiveDebugger/blob/master/app/build.gradle).

First, to answer part of the poster's question. The `org.antlr:antlr4-runtime:4.5.3` and `org.antlr:antlr4-tool:4.5.3` packages seem dated. Even though many older posts suggest using these dependencies. I have found that the following will include the most recent version of ANTLR4 (check the ANTLR4 repository for updated versions):

```
dependencies {
    // ...
    implementation 'org.antlr:antlr4:4.9.1'
}
```

With typical Android applications, we need to apply the following stock plugin first:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```

The problem is that this breaks Gradle's use with the ANTLR4 plugin. A work around is to install the `antlr4` utility in your shell path and then do something like the following in the application `build.gradle` configuration:

```
/* NOTE: The gradle plugin with Android does not work, this is a shell command within the standard system paths. */
def generateAntlrJava(String grammarFile) {
    def scriptRunCmd = "antlr -o app/src/main/antlr-gen -package 'com.my.package.name' -Dlanguage=Java" +
            " -listener -visitor -long-messages -lib 'path/to'" +
            " -Xexact-output-dir 'path/to" + grammarFile + "'";
    def cmdResult = ['bash', '-c', scriptRunCmd].execute();
    cmdResult.waitFor();
    return cmdResult.text
}

task PreBuildGenAntlr4JavaSources {
    println 'REMOVING OLD ANTLR4 JAVA SOURCES ==> '
    file(new File('app/src/main/antlr-gen')).deleteDir()
    println 'GENERATING ANTLR4 JAVA SOURCES ==> '
    file(new File('app/src/main/antlr-gen')).mkdirs()
    generateAntlrJava("MyScriptLexer.g4")
    generateAntlrJava("MyScriptParser.g4")
    outputs.upToDateWhen { false } /* Make the task run every time (no UP-TO-DATE skippage) */
}
preBuild.dependsOn PreBuildGenAntlr4JavaSources

task cleanPreBuildGenAntlr4JavaSources {
    println 'REMOVING OLD ANTLR4 JAVA SOURCES ==> '
    file(new File('app/src/main/antlr-gen')).deleteDir()
    println 'GENERATING ANTLR4 JAVA SOURCES ==> '
    file(new File('app/src/main/antlr-gen')).mkdirs()
    generateAntlrJava("MyScriptLexer.g4")
    generateAntlrJava("MyScriptParser.g4")
}
clean.dependsOn cleanPreBuildGenAntlr4JavaSources
```

That's it. The only solution that worked for my use case :)